# glassfish launch application empty no links

Tags: glassfish, hyperlink, launch

My application runs good, i see the log no error. When i am on the `DAS Administration` page (`port 4848`), i have my application with my projtect, i can't access to the link page? Normally i should have:  `Links: [server] http://...  :80/myappl` and i have Links.

What should i check?

Thanks

I found in the config of glassfish Configuration/server-config/Network Config/Network Listener/http-listener 1 check Status ENABLED